# XPATH: Find nodes which contain specific attribute and exclude some node and their childnodes

Tags: xml, dom, xpath, nodes, element

I would like to parse schemadata from HTML and arrange data using XPATH.

*Schema data information

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Product">

  <div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="birthday" datetime="2009-05-10">May 10th 2009</span>
  </div>

  <div itemprop="name"> Product name </div>
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="price" content="500.00"> USD 500 </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

The desired result would be like this:
[image]
To parse category, product and person, I used this code:

```
var category = $x("//*[@itemtype and not(@itemprop)]"); 
//category[0] = <div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Product">
//category[1] = <div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Person">
```

In case of `category[0]`, before I parse elements which has attribute "itemprop", I have to exclude `category[1]`, because `category[0]` includes `category[1]`.

I made this code, however I cannot combine several conditions into one.

```
var category = $x("//*[@itemtype and not(@itemprop)]");
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. var product = $x("//*[@itemprop and not(@itemtype)]", category[0]);

2.Under category[0] nodes, I would like to exclude these nodes which met this condition, 
[contains(@itemtype,'schema.org/') and not(@itemprop)]/descendant-or-self::*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I exclude `category[1]` node and their childnodes in `category[0]` to get desired result? I think I have to combine those 1 and 2 conditions into one, but I have no idea. Please shed light on this matter.

Many thanks, Happy Thanksgiving Day :)

Comment: If you use a less specific selector with a hierarchy structure, it's always posible that you end up selecting an ancestor and some descendant. And because you are just selecting, when you process the ancestor you have to acknowledge that it contains its decendant.

Comment: @Alejandro Could you give me some clues? I can't understand yet.

Comment: You need to show us how you are producing the output.

Comment: I added some codes on the post.

Comment: Do you understand that in your code you are *selecting* an existing element, thus all the subtree rooted at that element isn't going to change no matter what would be the expression used to select it?

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks for your reply. Yes, after I searched XPATH syntax, I understand that. //ancestor::*[@itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Product"]//descendant::*[@itemprop and not(ancestor::*[@itemtype and not(@itemprop)])] I used this code but there's a conflict due to this part "ancestor::*[@itemtype and not(@itemprop)'" How can I exclude the top element on this part?